# Random Image in CSS background in Tumblr theme

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question may have been asked before but I'm a complete HTML noob and none of the answers I have found have helped me.

In my Tumblr theme, the header is set like this:

```
.siteHeader {
        {block:ifShowHeaderImage}
        background: url({HeaderImage}) no-repeat center center {block:ifFixedHeaderBackground}fixed{/block:ifFixedHeaderBackground};
        background-size: cover;
        {/block:ifShowHeaderImage}
        color: {color:Header Text};
    }
```

with `{HeaderImage}` referring to Tumblr's preset account header image that exists within the Tumblr infrastructure. I want the header image on my actual theme to randomise across multiple images that are already hosted on Tumblr and I have the direct URLs for.

Could someone please walk me through how to implement this? I've found plenty of Javascript scripts but they only work for replacing `<img src>` and plenty of PHP scripts but Tumblr does not support those.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jquery to change CSS parameters.

```
 $('.siteHeader').css( "background-image", "url(yourURL)" );
```

or if it's a variable

```
 $('.siteHeader').css( "background-image", "url(" + yourURLVariable + ")" );
```

This is a complete example with an array. If you use this, ignore anything above here.

```
 // Fill in the URL to your images here in place of 'url1', 'url2' and so on
 var urlArray = [
   'url1',
   'url2'
 ];

 // Script selects a random number here on it's own
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * urlArray.length);
 // Script now sets the background-image css with jQuery here
 $('.siteHeader').css( "background-image", "url(" + urlArray[randomNumber]+ ")" );
```

Comment: And? Did this help you? Could you solve your problem with this?

Comment: No, sorry, like I said I have no idea what I'm doing. Where do all these bits of code need to go?

Comment: Try starting out here:
http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/

Basically try wrapping the script I wrote your in a <script></script> tag at the bottom of your <body>.
Fill in the URL for your images in the array at the start of my script.

And of course you will have to link to include the links to the jqeury files in your template. Have you used any Java Script before, or is this totally new to you?

Comment: I did like the most basic Javascript Codecademy course but that was a while ago. I've got the script in at the bottom. But where do I put the first stuff? In with the CSS? And what needs to go in "yourURL"?

Comment: You only use the bottom part of my post! The part start with "var urlArray" and so on. That is a complete script. Fill in the URL to your pictures in the urlArray part. So instead of 'url1' and so on you put in the url to your image. You can put in as many images as you like, separated by commas. That should make it work.

Comment: I've added more comments to the script. Hope that makes it easier for you.

Comment: Any luck doing this? If yes: please mark question as answered.

Comment: No, sorry! Put the script in, with two image URLs just to start with but it's not working. Could it be that the CSS calls upon 'HeaderImage' whereas your script calls upon 'background-image'?

Comment: To help you, the Tumblr is http://thelastofus-photography.tumblr.com/ and I've pasted the entire HTML for you here (http://pastebin.com/uxQY9Ne6) with your script in at the bottom at line 817.

Comment: It works! The .siteHeader part of your code need apostrophes around it like so: ('.siteHeader'). Thanks so much! For accuracy's sake, change the answer to include this and I'll mark it as correct. Thank you so so much for all your help!

Comment: Oops. My bad. Was a little too quick I guess. Glad I could help :D

Comment: Btw: You can add more images to the random selection. Just add another to the "var urlArray" section and seperate by a comma. The last entry has no comma!

For example:
    
 var urlArray = [
       'url1',
       'url2',
       'url3',
       'url4'
     ];

And so on. Remember: last entry has no comma! ;)